# Misaligned div in code

Tags: html, css

Atm I trying to resolve somekind of an headache with my code. I want to put a image on the left side of my site. And on the right side I want some text to appear that are centered on the left side and still aligned to the left. I sort of got It working but now I have a problem where my codes div on my site are misaligned and with that I mean... you can see in the link (obviously without the borders, just for illustration)

https://codepen.io/JessenJonas/pen/mjmVJd

The point is that the text on the right has to be centered both vertical and horizontal. But as you can see it is aligned centered in both ways it is just misaligned. How do I fix this?

```
Code  code code
why do I have to make
4 spaces of code
just to link a codepen??
```

Comment: `why do I have to make
4 spaces of code
just to link a codepen??` --> you have to include the code here, and it's not too much you can easily do a copy/paste

Comment: Wait where? In the comments?

Comment: in your question ....

Comment: Okay i will rememner that to the next time

Comment: @JessenJonas you should add the code to this question, or you will not get any answers. Use "edit" button under question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very easy solution is to put `style="vertical-align:middle"` in your image element, so you get:

```
<img src="https://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/A-fluffy-cat-looking-funny-surprised-or-concerned.jpg" alt="cat" style="vertical-align:middle">
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qymaPG)